# ubuntu16.04にNS2をセットアップできません

Tags: ubuntu

ubuntu16.04LTSにNS2を導入しています。
しかしこのようなエラーが表示されます。

```
*******************$ns
%nam
child killed: segmentation violation
```

どのような処理を施せばNS2をセットアップすることができるでしょうか。
すみませんがご教授お願いします。

以下にセットアップ方法を記します。

1. セットアップ済のUbuntuにns-allinone-2.35.tar.gzを移動。
2. 端末を起動、`tar zxvf ns-allinone-2.35.tar.gz`実行
3. `sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake libxmu-dev`
4. 解凍してできたディレクトリcd ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/linkstate/に移動
5. `gedit ls.h`
   ファイルls.hを一部変更
   137行目

   ```
   Void eraseALL(){erase(baseMap::begin() , base::end());}
   ```

   ↓

   ```
   Void eraseALL(){ this->erase(baseMap::begin() , base::end());}
   ```

   (※`this->`を追加)
6. ns-allinone-2.35/で`./install`
7. ホームディレクトリに戻る

   ```
   gedit .bashrc
   ```

   ファイル.bashrcの最後に追記。ユーザ名はUbuntuセットアップ時に自分で設定したものを入力。
   一番下に追加

   ```sh
   # LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   OTCL_LIB=/home/ユーザ名/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14
   NS2_LIB=/home/ユーザ名/ns-allinone-2.35/lib
   X11_LIB=/usr/X11R6/lib
   USR_LOCAL_LIB=/usr/local/lib
   export　LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$OTCL_LIB:$NS2_LIB:$X11_LIB:$USR_LOCAL_LIB
   # TCL_LIBRARY　
   TCL_LIB=/home/ユーザ名/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/library
   USR_LIB=/usr/lib
   export TCL_LIBRARY=$TCL_LIB:$USR_LIB
   # PATH
   XGRAPH=/home/ユーザ名/ns-allinone-2.35/bin:/home/ユーザ名/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/unix:/home/ユーザ名/ns-allinone-2.35/tk8.5.10/unix
   #the above two lines beginning from xgraph and ending with unix should come on the same line
   NS=/home/ユーザ名/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/ 
   NAM=/home/ユーザ名/ns-allinone-2.35/nam-1.15/ 
   PATH=$PATH:$XGRAPH:$NS:$NAM
   ```

8.　端末で`ns`　プロンプト｢%｣が表示されることを確認
9.　`nam`を入力NAM - The Network Animatorが起動すれば完了

エラーと同時に「残念ながら、アプリケーションnamが予期せず停止しました。」とUbuntuのウィンドウが表示されます。

追記：

```
$ gcc --version
 gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609
```

Ubuntu日本語フォーラムでも同様の質問をさせていただいております。
https://forums.ubuntulinux.jp/viewtopic.php?id=20177

Comment: Docker 上の Ubuntu 16.04 (gcc 5.4.0, autoconf 2.69) において質問文に書かれていたものと同じ手順を再現してみましたが、`ns` のプロンプト上で `nam` を入力しても正常にウィンドウが立ち上がってしまいました。何か明文化されていない差に原因があるようです。たとえば、`gcc --version` の結果を質問文に追記して頂けませんでしょうか？

Comment: 「ns のプロンプト上で nam を入力しても正常にウィンドウが立ち上がってしまいました。」とは、ns2が正常に起動したということでしょうか。 gcc --version の結果を追記いたしました。

Comment: nekketsuuuさん、書体の編集･修正ありがとうございます。autoconfもnekketsuuuさんと同様、autoconf 　2.69でした

Comment: シェル上で `ulimit -c unlimited` を実行して、次に `nam` を実行します（こちらもシェル上で）。Segmentation violation が発生したのち、nam を実行したディレクトリに `core` という名前のファイルが作成されているはずなので、同じくシェル上で `gdb $(which nam) core` を実行すると、どの辺りでエラーが発生したのかが分かるかもしれません。ただ、デバッグオプションを付けないでコンパイルされているかと思いますので、あまり有用な情報は得られないかもしれません。

Comment: metropolisさん、コメントありがとうございます。有用な情報はなさそうでした。お忙しい中回答していただきありがとうございます。

Comment: 要望があったため、議論のためのチャットを作成いたしました： https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85662/discussion-on-question-by-chihiro-ubuntu16-04ns2

Answer (score 1):

この問題はnamのバージョンを1.14にした事により解決することが出来ました。
みなさん、ありがとうございました。